# Find integer row-index from pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, indices

The following code find index where df['A'] == 1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

index = range(10)
random.shuffle(index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,1)).astype(int), columns = ['A'], index = index)

df.A.iloc[3:6] = 1
df.A.iloc[6:] = 2

print df

print df.loc[df['A'] == 1].index.tolist()
```

It returns pandas index correctly. How do I get the integer index ([3,4,5]) instead using pandas API?

```
   A
8  0
4  0
6  0
3  1
7  1
1  1
5  2
0  2
2  2
9  2
[3, 7, 1]
```

Comment: These are called *'row-indices*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
df.reset_index().index[df.A == 1].tolist()
```

This re-indexes the data frame with `[0, 1, 2, ...]`, then extracts the integer index values based on the boolean mask `df.A == 1`.

---

**Edit** Credits to @Max for the `index[df.A == 1]` idea.

Answer (score 4):

what about?

```
In [12]: df.index[df.A == 1]
Out[12]: Int64Index([3, 7, 1], dtype='int64')
```

or (depending on your goals):

```
In [15]: df.reset_index().index[df.A == 1]
Out[15]: Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Demo:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   A
8  0
4  0
6  0
3  1
7  1
1  1
5  2
0  2
2  2
9  2

In [12]: df.index[df.A == 1]
Out[12]: Int64Index([3, 7, 1], dtype='int64')

In [15]: df.reset_index().index[df.A == 1]
Out[15]: Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for numpy, you're right. Just pure python with a listcomp:

Just find the indexes where the values are 1

```
print([i for i,x in enumerate(df['A'].values) if x == 1])
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this in pandas. Shouldn't this be implemented in pandas?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Your first question mentionned "no numpy", not "with pandas". I'm just proposing a python-only solution.

Comment: My bad, I was not expressing myself well at first haha

Comment: not a problem. Now there are 3 valid answers which have their own qualities :)